# Hide or Unhide Spreadsheets based on other sheet column values

Tags: google-apps-script

I have couple of sheets with different names. From the "Menu" tab I can refer all the spreadsheets.
Col A = SPreadsheet Name
Col B = Hide or UnHide

Other spreadsheets would be Hide/Unhide based on "Menu" tab "Col B".

Please help out on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this script to hide or unhide sheets:

```
function hide() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menu = ss.getSheetByName("Menu");
  var sheetAttributes = menu.getRange(2,1,menu.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();

  for(i=0;i<sheetAttributes.length;i++) {
    if (sheetAttributes[i][1] == 'Hide') {
      ss.getSheetByName(sheetAttributes[i][0]).hideSheet();
    }
    if (sheetAttributes[i][1] == 'Unhide') {
      ss.getSheetByName(sheetAttributes[i][0]).showSheet();
    }
  }
  
}
```

Sample sheet:

[image]

[image]